# using react-router in Next.js environment

Tags: react-router, next.js

I am currently using next.js framework. Is it possible to route components out of /pages directory?
Would not like to use 'react-router' (because it'll be complicated to edit server.js). If it is inevitable I will but is there any other way?

Comment: Next.js comes with a built-in router, that is a backbone of it architecture, it is not recommended to use other routers. saying this, there is https://github.com/toomuchdesign/next-react-router that you can checkout

Comment: Thank you so much for you answer but I already checked out that post :0                 I wanted to know is there any ways that I can access components out of /pages directory by using only next-router syntax(?)

Comment: You can access components in any directory, the `pages` components are mapped to routes by next.

Comment: I meant to say 'that I can access components by the URL,  out of /pages directory" I believe that is hard one to do in next.js environment

Comment: It is not possible to target components out side of `pages` folder by url.

Comment: You can make a dynamic route in the pages folder of your next app: `[param].js`, and base on the value of `param` (`const router = useRouter()
  const { param } = router.query`), switch between components.

Answer (score 0):

im afraid this is not possible in nextjs. nextjs builds its route view pages folder.  what you can do that wont ruin your project structure or URLs is to

add your components to the new repo.
create your pages folder based on your routes in pervious project.
add index.js in each pages folder.
and import the main component instead of actually moving it to pages folder, for example:

```
export { default } from './components/users';
```

this way you can drag and drop your existing structure and only add your route as pages folders.
notes to consider:

1. next default routing is case sensitive so be careful about your folder names if you want a work around for that you should use nextjs v12 create all pages to lower case and config your project to translate all routes to lower case.
2. you can have nested routes by adding nested folder:

```
pages 
   userslist
     userdetail 
      index.js
```

this structure will create this route:
/userlist/userdetail

3. if you have components you dont want for user to be accessible **do not** put them in pages
4. if you have dynamic routes such as id in your route you can specify it by adding a folder in pages like [id] and redirect to it following this syntax

```
Router.push(`/sth/sth/${sth.id}`);
```

5. this configuration of [redirects](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/redirects) in nextjs might come in handy when you need to custom your links

i should also warn you migrating an existing project to nextjs requires a lot of work and a lot of changes to the project.